# combineLatest() glitch and fail try with debounceTIme - Angular

Tags: angular

I am using the combineLatest operator to subscribe to five observables at the time.
First I made the suscription and then I realized the glitch in the data charge.

It is being readed and getting the last data of each suscription until gets the final result. If I see it on the redux devTool, I can see how three different results are charged before the definitive one.

Finally, I found a "solution" in a blog: debounceTime, rxjs operator. But I think I am not using the right syntax and it is not working.

I am really frustrated with this, so, I would appreciate any help or orientation.

My code is:

```
  getAllSubscriptions() {
        this.subscription.add(
          combineLatest([
            this.logginFacade.isNewestVersion$,
            this.logginFacade.logginPermissions$,
            this.foodFacade.foodRecord$,
            this.tablesFacade.tableRecord$,
            this.scheduleFacade.scheduleRecord$
          ]).subscribe(
            ([newestVersion, permissions, food, table, schedule]: [
              boolean,
              LogginPermissions,
              Food[],
              Tables[],
              Schedule[]
            ]) => {
              this.getMessage (
                newestVersion,
                permissions,
                food,
                tables,
                schedule
              );
            }
          )
        ),
          debounceTime(0);
      }
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: DebounceTime should be in a pipe, before your subscription

Answer (score 0):

`debounceTime` is an operator so it needs to be in a pipe like this:

```
getAllSubscriptions() {
  this.subscription.add(
    combineLatest([
      this.logginFacade.isNewestVersion$,
      this.logginFacade.logginPermissions$,
      this.foodFacade.foodRecord$,
      this.tablesFacade.tableRecord$,
      this.scheduleFacade.scheduleRecord$
    ])
      .pipe(
        debounce(() => timer(1000))
      )
      .subscribe(
        ([newestVersion, permissions, food, tables, schedule]: [
          boolean,
          LogginPermissions,
          Food[],
          Tables[],
          Schedule[]
        ]) => {
          this.getMessage (
            newestVersion,
            permissions,
            food,
            tables,
            schedule
          );
        }
      )
  )
}
```

Update: You need to pass a function not a value into debounce. See updates.

NOTE: You had a type table vs. tables in your subscribe arrow function parameters too.